# Flash AS3 touch screen non mobile solution

Tags: windows, actionscript-3, touch, flash

Good day, im having a touchscreen panel (resistive) on my test PC (Running Windows 8 - non mobile!).

Im enabled touch mode: *Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;*

**MouseEvent.CLICK** on tap not working with my movie_clip/button.

**TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP** - is too **not working**.

Im control
**Multitouch.maxTouchPoints** return **0**

but property **Multitouch.supportsTouchEvents** return **true**

**Multitouch.maxTouchPoints** it should return return **1**???

Sorry bad English.

Answer (score 0):

Multitouch.maxTouchPoints is the maximum number of concurrent touch points. If this is only 1 for your system this is equivalent to using MouseEvents.

In fact even Adobe states that using the TouchListeners consumes more resources than MouseEventListeners (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WSb2ba3b1aad8a27b0-6ffb37601221e58cc29-8000.html).

You might be better off disabling all TouchEvents either by setting
`Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.NONE;` or by simply deleting 
`Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;`

Your app will still react to touch just that Actionscript calls it MouseEvent.
If you want to handle gestures yourself you can listen to:

```
MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN
MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE
MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP
```

Comment: Im tested, flash not responding on click(

Comment: Im using flash player as ActiveX in windows forms app, maybe problem this?